# Difference between .tdb and .dylib in iOS (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add `libsqlite3.dylib` in my project using Xcode 7 beta. I searched in "Link Binary with Libraries", but I found a library like this, `libsqlite3.tdb`.
Is it any difference between **.tdb** and .**dylib**? Please describe the difference between these two and whether this will work on iOS 8 and lower.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add .dylib go to your project targets -> Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries -> Click plus button -> Add Other -> press command + shift + g -> Enter "/Usr/lib" -> click Go -> Search "libz" -> Select from the list and click open.

Answer (score 9):

**.dylib** is the compiled binary that contains the machine code. **.tdb** is a text file akin to a cross-platform module map. I can only assume it's there so that you can write Swift code and link it against Unix libraries that are shared between Darwin / Linux. We'll know soon enough.

Here's the beginning of *libssl.tdb*

```
---
archs:           [ i386, x86_64 ]
platform:        macosx
install-name:    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
current-version: 0.9.8
compatibility-version: 0.9.8
exports:         
  - archs:           [ i386, x86_64 ]
    symbols:         [ _BIO_f_ssl, _BIO_new_buffer_ssl_connect, _BIO_new_ssl, 
                       _BIO_new_ssl_connect, _BIO_ssl_copy_session_id,
```